# auto answer the phone and play a pre-recorded sound file.in iphone?

Tags: iphone

HI,
i want to create an iphone.
The app should be able to auto answer the phone and play a pre-recorded sound file.
Can it be done without using private frameworks??
if yes, than any suggestions, how can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can not be done with out private frameworks.